# Is there a built-in method to calculate Precision in scikit's learn random forest classifier?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I am running a random forest classifier using scikit's learn, and would like to calculate a precision metric (how many predictions matched the target value) as part of the results. Is there a built-in option to do that? If not what would be the easiest way to implement it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see the reference documentation on performance metrics: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics